# how to autoinvoke functions in array (ecma6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following:

```
const a = val => val;
const b = [a];
const results = b.map(fn => fn('x'));
```

I would love to avoid creating extra function in map, so that I could get results with something like this: (I know this way I would not be able to pass a param either)

```
const results = b.map(Function.call); // This is not working
```

Chrome console shows following error when I do that:

> VM1075:3 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I also tried using:

```
const results = b.map(Function.prototype.call);
```

1) Why is it not working/Why I am receiving this error?

2)

- How could I fix it?
- How could I fix it passing always same parameter? (Something like Function.call.bind(this, 'param')

Comment: Im do not get it, is const 'a' a function? I mean is b an array of functions?

Comment: yes, it is, in ecma 5 it would transpile to var a = function(val) { return val }

Comment: Something like this may be? https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/md0ubrhk/ . What's wrong with `b.map(fn => fn('x'))` anyway?

Comment: It's not "wrong". I just want to make use of javascript API, so I do not need to create extra functions. I think there must be a way to just use Function.prototype.call/apply, I just need to know how to use it properly. Your solution avoids creating a new anonymous function per iteration tho, that's nice. Let's see if someone knows how to avoid the necessity of creating my own function though. Tyvm :)

Comment: As far as I know, and I have been searching some time, there is nothing  like `invoke` in javascript to call a function passed as an argument. Upvote, and waiting for a response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map(Function.call)` won't work because the context is lost when a method is passed as a callback. And the context is supposed to be a callee itself. So in order for this to work as expected (without bound `'x'`) it should be

```
.map(fn => Function.call.bind(fn)())
```

Considering that second `'x'` argument is supposed to be bound to mapper function *after* first `fn` argument, map callback just cannot be obtained with a chain of `call` and `bind` methods alone.

The way it's normally done in ES6 is

```
const xMapper = fn => fn('x');
...
const results = b.map(xMapper);
```

And anonymous `map` callback is perfectly fine if there are no concerns about readability and reusability.

Comment: Thats exactly the kind of answer I needed, a real explanation of what was happenning :) tyvm

Answer (score 0):

if you always want to call a function with the same param passed in, then you can do something like this:

```
const a = val => val;
const b = [a]

const protofn = param => fn => fn(param);
const fn = protofn('hello');

const results = b.map(fn);
console.log(results)
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`map` function expect callback function that is called for every item in the array. If you want to avoid creating anonymous functions, you can define it ahead and pass it to map.

```
const a = val => val;
const b = [a];
const myCall = fn => fn();
const results = b.map(myCall);
```

You are trying to pass `Function.call` which has other purpose.
Personally, I see no reason not to use the first approach:

```
const results = b.map(fn => fn('x'));
```